# Custom Action for Wix Installer failing after first time run

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have been trying to implement msi installation using msiexec and passing custom parameter to it.

```
msiexec /i somefile.msi /l*v output.txt IPADDRESS="127.0.0.1" PORT="9999"
```

Now I have following code that does the work of getting the IPADDRESS and PORT and write them to a file. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace SetupCA
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult WriteFileToDisk(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin WriteFileToDisk");

            string ipAddress = session["IPADDRESS"];
            string port = session["PORT"];
            string temp = @"
{{
 ""ip"" : ""{0}"" ,
""port"" : ""{1}""
}}";
            string config = string.Format(temp, ipAddress, port);
            session.Log("Config Generated was " + config);  
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\somefolder");
            try{
                 System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\somefolder\\some.config");
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\somefolder\some.config", config); 
            session.Log("Ending WriteFileToDisk");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: Full Wix Code**
I have used the dll file generated in Wix given as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="CustomWixInstallerWithCustomAction" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Developer" UpgradeCode="ba9015b9-027f-4451-adb2-e38f9168a850">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="no" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="CustomWixInstallerWithCustomAction" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="CustomWixInstaller" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="SomeRandomEXE">
    <File Source ="some.exe" />
  </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
<Binary Id="SetupCA"  SourceFile="SetupCA.CA.dll"/>
<CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Sequence="2"></Custom>

</InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>
```

Everything is working fine when I install the msi using the command given above. The text file is generated in folder with the contents given during parameter. But when I use the same command, these parameter are not fetched and written in file. But if I uninstall it using:

```
msiexec /x file.msi
```

and running again, it works. What is the problem here?

Comment: Sorry, but for me it is not clear, what you are trying. Especially, what you mean with the sentence "Everything is working fine...using the command given above. [...] But when I use the same (???) command,...". Second: What you are trying to do, just logging the ip and the port given in commandline to another config-file? Or would you like to take the two msi properties out of a config file? Third, and most important. What does the msi logfile say, is your custom action started or not. Without this information, we cannot say anything.

Comment: The dll compiled by the program is used inside Custom Action in Wix, which is supposed to fetch the parameters given to the msifile and write those parameter in some config file. When I run the msi file using the command above, it does all the work correctly and creates config file. When I run the same command for second time and so on, those parameters are not fetched and config file looks like {"ip:"","port":""} . If i uninstall the msifile using command given below and install it again, it does works. Is there something wrong in my code.

Comment: @SarvagyaPant You can't execute the same installer over and over, the MSI will detect that it is currently installed and abort the installation. If I'm not wrong you are thinking in repair or upgrade. If that's the case you need to configure your installer to behave properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolo has given the correct answer first in a comment:

More in detail:
If you call a msi setup the second time, you cannot expect it, to do the same as during first time.
First called (if all goes well) it does an install, second time called, it does nearly nothing, recognizing that the product is already installed.

Uninstall it in between or use the "REINSTALL=ALL" parameter (together with other options like REINSTALLMODE, maybe), then a repair/reinstall is done.

Even if your custom action would work for "the second call" it would be nothing worth. It is like trying to hack a light switch at a wall. One could say: "I have wired the switch to an Arduino and every time someone switches the light on, an alarm sounds. But unfortunately, if I hit on the light switch the second time while the light is still on, it doesn't work..."

Hope that example helps to show the MSI idea behind.

--
Moreover to that:

For what you want, an experienced msi person would not use a custom action. The "IniFile table" is made for such things. Built-in features are likely more reliable for the whole MSI space than custom actions, allowing as only one example to work also in deferred custom actions, which is e.g. necessary in some security scenarios. A simple custom action cannot read properties in such scenarios easily.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/04/03/from-msi-to-wix-part-15-installable-items-ini-files.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Though I have to use the Custom Action, the idea of Using Inifile Table seems good too.

Comment: How am I supposed to perform the task using the Inifile if I have to use it.

Comment: Hello! You have not to perform anything, just fill the IniFile table. I have given some links for that and googling would find more info.MSI is performing it for you at the right place. If you are interested in internal details look at the execution sequence (you have download Orca, Insted or anything else as a recommendation in each case) of your MSI, and you will find the 'WriteIniValues' action.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your entire WiX file, it will be hard to tell you what is going wrong.  There are many elements which may be blocking it.  But from what it sounds like, I don't think the custom action is firing in the case overinstall.

In my other answer to your other question which got you this far, I suggested putting:

```
        session.Log("Begin WriteFileToDisk");
```

In your customAction.  This is exactly the reason - for debugging.  In the SECOND time you run the installer, do you see those lines (for Begin and End) in the output log?

Lastly, a tool that might help you will be the ORCA.exe tool.
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

That tool will let you open your msi file, and see all the configurations that were setup.  So you can see if there is a condition set for your custom action being called.

Comment: For the second run of same MSI i do get the statements Begin WriteFileToDisk and End WriteFileToDsik in Log. What I don't get is the parameters passed to MSI

Comment: If the begin and end are being written, then the custom action is running, but maybe in repair mode? I am not sure. From what I understood, the properties should be set in repair mode as well, but maybe they are not?